# Are there any detailed docs on how to interact with smart contracts of `ink!`?

Tags: ink

Currently, I only found a way to interact with smart contracts using the [contracts UI](https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/).

Are there any detailed docs on how to interact with `ink!` smart contracts with polkadot.js or something else?

Comment: Are you talking about interactions from a user point of view, or a developer point of view? E.g, are you interested in learning how to use the Polkadot JS Apps UI (or another UI/tool), or the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this [polkadot.js](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract) what you need?

Comment: Actually, I know the docs you mentioned~ But I think there's not enough information there. So are there any docs with more details?